# Search by first and last name of the Instructor

Tags: mysql, string-searching, like

I have the below tables in the MySQL database

```
create table course_class
(
    id                      varchar(36)   not null primary key,
    class_code              varchar(255)  not null,
    course_code             varchar(255)  null,
    description             longtext      null,
    end_date                datetime      null,
    name                    varchar(255)  null,
    start_date              datetime      null,
);

create table role
(
    id            varchar(36)  not null primary key,
    name          varchar(255) null,
);

create table user
(
    id             varchar(36)  not null primary key,
    first_name     varchar(255) not null,
    gender         varchar(255) null,
    last_name      varchar(255) not null,
    middle_name    varchar(255) null,
    username       varchar(255) not null,
);

create table course_class_user
(
    id                          varchar(36)  not null primary key,
    course_class_id             varchar(36)  not null,
    role_id                     varchar(36)  not null,
    user_id                     varchar(36)  not null,
    constraint FK_course_class_course_class_id
        foreign key (course_class_id) references course_class (id),
    constraint FK_course_class_user_role_id
        foreign key (role_id) references role (id),
    constraint FK_course_class_user_user_id
        foreign key (user_id) references user (id)
);
```

I have below requirement

> As a user I need the ability to get all classes an instructor is teaching.
>
> - It should support partial name search, the partial text can be either
>   in first_name or last_name. (UI has only one text field and they can give
>   partial first_name or last_name or both)
> - If one word is sent look for a partial match either in first_name or in last_name.
> - If both are provided, look for the partial match of both words in both fields.
> - Sort order shall be first_name and last_name

I am extracting `firstName` and `lastName` using the below code in java

```
String firstName = instructorName;
String lastName = StringUtils.SPACE;
if (instructorName.contains(StringUtils.SPACE)) {
    String[] fullName = instructorName.split(StringUtils.SPACE);
    firstName = fullName[0];
    lastName = fullName[1];
}
```

Variable `instructorName` holds user input, It can be `Monika Smith` or `Smith Monika` and for the above requirement, I have created the below query in java

```
@Query(value = "select cc from CourseClass cc "
        + "inner join CourseClassUser ccu on cc.id = ccu.courseClass.id "
        + "inner join Role r on ccu.role.id = r.id "
        + "inner join User u on ccu.user.id = u.id "
        + "where r.name = 'Instructor' and (u.firstName like %:firstName% or u.lastName like %:lastName% "
        + "or u.firstName like %:lastName% or u.lastName like %:firstName%) "
        + "order by u.firstName, u.lastName"
    )
```

It generates the below query for input `smith monika`

```
select cc from course_class cc
         inner join course_class_user ccu on cc.id = ccu.course_class_id
         inner join role r on ccu.role_id = r.id
         inner join user u on ccu.user_id = u.id
where r.name = 'Instructor' and (u.first_name like '%smith%' or u.last_name like '%monika%'
   or u.first_name like '%monika%' or last_name like '%smith%')
order by u.first_name, u.last_name;
```

and for input `monika` it generates the below query

```
select cc from course_class cc
         inner join course_class_user ccu on cc.id = ccu.course_class_id
         inner join role r on ccu.role_id = r.id
         inner join user u on ccu.user_id = u.id
where r.name = 'Instructor' and (u.first_name like '%monika%' or u.last_name like '% %'
   or u.first_name like '% %' or last_name like '%monika%')
order by u.first_name, u.last_name;
```

For now, the above query serves the purpose. I want to know if my query is efficient and correct or is there an alternate and efficient way to serve the requirement?

**Update 1**: Below is the output of `EXPLAIN`

```
+--+-----------+-----+----------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------+---------------------+----+--------+-------------------------------+
|id|select_type|table|partitions|type  |possible_keys                                                                            |key                            |key_len|ref                  |rows|filtered|Extra                          |
+--+-----------+-----+----------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------+---------------------+----+--------+-------------------------------+
|1 |SIMPLE     |cc   |NULL      |ALL   |PRIMARY                                                                                  |NULL                           |NULL   |NULL                 |9   |100     |Using temporary; Using filesort|
|1 |SIMPLE     |ccu  |NULL      |ref   |idx_user_course_class_tenant,FK_course_class_user_role_id,FK_course_class_course_class_id|FK_course_class_course_class_id|146    |classroom.cc.id      |7   |100     |NULL                           |
|1 |SIMPLE     |r    |NULL      |eq_ref|PRIMARY                                                                                  |PRIMARY                        |146    |classroom.ccu.role_id|1   |10      |Using where                    |
|1 |SIMPLE     |u    |NULL      |eq_ref|PRIMARY                                                                                  |PRIMARY                        |146    |classroom.ccu.user_id|1   |37.57   |Using where                    |
+--+-----------+-----+----------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------+---------------------+----+--------+-------------------------------+
```

Below is the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

```
-> Sort row IDs: u.first_name, u.last_name  (actual time=0.391..0.393 rows=6 loops=1)
    -> Table scan on <temporary>  (actual time=0.001..0.004 rows=6 loops=1)
        -> Temporary table  (cost=39.00 rows=2) (actual time=0.366..0.370 rows=6 loops=1)
            -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=39.00 rows=2) (actual time=0.096..0.323 rows=6 loops=1)
                -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=36.76 rows=6) (actual time=0.076..0.291 rows=7 loops=1)
                    -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=14.31 rows=64) (actual time=0.069..0.215 rows=57 loops=1)
                        -> Table scan on cc  (cost=1.15 rows=9) (actual time=0.032..0.045 rows=9 loops=1)
                        -> Index lookup on ccu using FK_course_class_course_class_id (course_class_id=cc.id)  (cost=0.83 rows=7) (actual time=0.016..0.018 rows=6 loops=9)
                    -> Filter: (r.`name` = 'Instructor')  (cost=0.25 rows=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=57)
                        -> Single-row index lookup on r using PRIMARY (id=ccu.role_id)  (cost=0.25 rows=1) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=57)
                -> Filter: ((u.first_name like '%fr%') or (u.last_name like '% %') or (u.first_name like '% %') or (u.last_name like '%fr%'))  (cost=0.26 rows=0) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=7)
                    -> Single-row index lookup on u using PRIMARY (id=ccu.user_id)  (cost=0.26 rows=1) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=7)
```

Comment: can you give a hint and tag which database you use. and you can also provide a explain of your queies

Comment: @nbk I am using MySQL I have updated the tag.

Comment: please add also EXPLAIN `your Query`

Comment: thus explain https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html  :)

Comment: @nbk I have added output of the Explain and Explain Analyze

Comment: `% %` checks for a space somewhere in the name.  I doubt if that is what you wanted.

Comment: If I search with lastName for eg `smith` and doesn't provide spaces in between `%%` i.e `(u.first_name like '%smith%' or u.last_name like '%%' or u.first_name like '%%' or last_name like '%smith%')` the query doesn't provide correct results.